# UPnP device accessible via public IP when on internal network only why?

Tags: networking, home-networking, firewall, wireless-router

Setup my Foscam IP camera last night on the wireless network using UPnP and was able to access it fine via the public IP  using another PC on the same network with no issues.

However when I tried to access it from work it doesn’t connect. I’m using a [Netgear CVG824G](http://www.netgear.com.au/service-provider/products/routers-and-gateways/cable-eMTAs/CVG824G.aspx) router. Is there a firewall setting that I’m overlooking?

Comment: There's a lot of things it could be. It could be a setting in your own device. It could be that your ISP filters the port you're using. It could be that your router can't forward that particular port. (For example, many routers can't forward port 80.)

Comment: Thanks Dave! Soon as changed to a different port other than 80 it worked!

Comment: Depending on the router, moving its administrative interface to a port other than 80 might let it forward port 80. It's also possible your ISP filters port 80.

Comment: Do NOT ever expose UPnP to the internet, hackers will surely take advantage of it as it has no security at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use your own NAT rules and try to not forward to a port which may be used by the router like the 21, 22, or 80.